# Where is the R default path for MAC

Tags: r, macos

I have entered some codes on R in a MAC and before closing R, it asks "Save workspace image?" and I clicked "Save", thinking it would save my codes. But I cannot find where is my codes? So where is the R default path for MAC and how can I find my codes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Saving the workspace != saving a script with the code.

Comment: The usual location for .R files on a mac is just in '~'. Use `setwd()` to set the working directory explicitly. Type `?setwd` in R to get help on this.

Comment: A MAC is not a Mac.  It means something different.  And, as Dason wrote, "codes" doesn't mean anything.  What exactly are you hoping to retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you just executed `save.image()` and then hit yes, your data was saved to a file called `.Rdata`

In terminal, type `ls -alh` in the same working directory and you'll see it.

If you're not sure what dir you're in, in R type `getwd()`

Answer (score 0):

`save.image` will not save the commands that created the data objects in the `.Rdata` file. Instead you need to look at the `.Rhistory` file that is automatically saved at the end of a session. The default path is the working directory. If you were using the R.app or R64.app  GUI working environment then the name of the file is ".Rapp.history", but if it was a Terminal session it is named ".history". In an R session you can get the last 25 lines by typing `history()`. If you put a numerical argument in that `history` call, you can change the number of lines displayed.

```
?history
?getwd
```

Also look at the R Mac FAQ. It describes how the R.app GUI is different than what you might read in `?loadhistory`. You probably also need to learn how to see "dot-files" or "system files". This has long been possible by opening Terminal and typing at the command line:

```
 machine-name:dir username$ defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES:
```

Reboot or relaunch Finder. I keep my .Rhistory (those saved from a Terminal launch of R) and .Rhistory.history (those from an R-GUI launched session) files in the "root" of my User folder.